# changeing language files in JTSage Date and Time Picker plugin for jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-plugins, datebox

I can't find a way how to Change the language on a the databox

this are my codesnippets
I am loading the language files

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/i8n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../js/i8n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.de.js"></script>

  <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="langSelect">
     <label for="picklang">
      Language</label>
    <select name="picklang" id="picklang" data-native-menu="false">
      <option value="en">[en] English US</option>
      <option value="de" selected="selected">[de] German</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div data-role="fieldcontain" id="calendar">
     <input name="startDate" type="date" data-role="datebox" id="startDate" data-options='{"mode": "flipbox", "useLang": "de"}' />
  </div>
```

I want to change the localisation of the databox according to the selected values of #picklang and I am using therefore the following script code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).delegate('#picklang', 'change', function () {
    var val = $("#picklang option:selected").val();
    alert(val);
    $('#startDate').attr('data-options', '{"mode": "flipbox", "useLang":"' + val + '"}');
  });
```

A this is the problem. The alert shows the selected value but the databox (=flipbox) shows the same values as before (= after loading the page).

Is there anybody, who can give me advice?
Michael

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little snippet that will not only load the newly selected language dynamically, but it will change to the new selection on every datebox on the page.

```
$('.opt-pop-lang').live('change', function() {
  newLang = $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/i18n/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n." + newLang + ".utf8.js",
    success: function(data) {
      eval(data);
      var x = $.mobile.datebox.prototype.options.lang[newLang];
      $(document).find('[data-role=datebox]').each(function() {
        $(this).data('mobileDatebox').options.lang[newLang] = x;
        $(this).data('mobileDatebox').options.useLang = newLang;
      });
    }
  });
});
```

It may be more than you need, but the .useLang line is what is changing the language.  The bits before are pulling in the file and injecting it into each datebox instance.

Comment: Oh, if you want to see it in action, that's what drives the language picker on all the demo pages.