# Change the language of jqm DateBox plugin programmatically

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, localization, datebox

I’m looking for a way to programmatically change the language of the jqm DateBox plugin.
I’ve included the language files in my header section:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jqmDateBox/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jqmDateBox/jqm-datebox.mode.flipbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jqmDateBox/jquery.mousewheel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jqmDateBox/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.de.utf8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jqmDateBox/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.en.utf8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jqmDateBox/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.fr.utf8.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jqmDateBox/jquery.mobile.datebox.i18n.it.utf8.js"></script>
```

I’ve tried to change the language using the following code snippet ([changeing language files in JTSage Date and Time Picker plugin for jQueryMobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17516449/changeing-language-files-in-jtsage-date-and-time-picker-plugin-for-jquerymobile)):

```
var x = $.mobile.datebox.prototype.options.lang[newLang];
$(document).find('[data-role=datebox]').each(function () {
    $(this).data('mobileDatebox').options.lang[newLang] = x;
    $(this).data('mobileDatebox').options.useLang = "de";
});
```

But this gives me the following exception:

```
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'options' of undefined or null reference.
```

How can I change the language of the jqm DateBox plugin programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

I’ve found a way to change the language…

```
setDateInputOptions($("#dateInput"), "de");
function setDateInputOptions(input, language) {
        input.datebox("option", {
            "mode": "flipbox",
            "useFocus": true,
            "useButton": false,
            "useNewStyle": true,
            "overrideDateFormat": "%d.%m.%Y",
            "overrideDateFieldOrder": ["d", "m", "y"],
            "useLang": language
        });
    }
```